# derivative for finite positive integral K

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, machine-learning

I can't figure out what this question is asking for,

> Compute the derivative with respect to x of the function
>
> $$
> f(x) = \log\left(\sum_{k = 1}^K \exp(k x^k)\right)\:\text{ for finite, positive, integral }K.
> $$

I am assuming that I need to take the derivative of this function where:

$$
\frac{df(u)}{dx} = \frac{df}{du}\frac{du}{dx}
$$ where $u=\sum_{k = 1}^K \exp(k x^k)  f = log(u)$

And yes, it is an assignment question, in my Machine Learning class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your definition of $u$, what you are asked to find is
$$
\frac{df}{dx}=\frac{d}{dx}\log u=\frac{d\log u}{du}\,\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{1}{u}\,\,u'.
$$
I'm sure you can find $u'$.

Comment: Is that it? I thought there must be a catch, what does *integral K* in this context mean? and If you can compute u' ... only for documentation.. that will be great.

Comment: The integer $K$ is just the upper limit of the summation.$$\sum_{k=1}^K\exp(k\,x^k))=\exp x+\exp(2\,x^2)+\dots+\exp(K\,x^K).$$